# Difference between "extremities" and "extremes"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between *extremities* and *extremes*?

Which is more appropriate when attempting to convey that someone blows things out of proportion or is a bit hyperbolic? For context, this is the title of a sub-chapter.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, I think if you're looking for a noun from the adjective *extreme*, ***extremity*** (singular) is your best bet - meaning "extreme-ness".

Ex: *The extremity of his reaction*

The words *extremity* (singular or plural) and *extremes* have a few separating points.

One is that *extremities* can refer to physical things (your hands and feet, the borderlands of of country), while *extremes* generally mark ranges (as in temperature, weight, etc.) and other more abstract concepts.

Another difference is that *extremity*, as noted above, can be used to mean "extreme-ness", whereas *extremes* doesn't convey that meaning. Thus, *the extremity of his pain* makes more sense than *the extremes of his pain*.

*Extremity* is also the word used when describing dire situations. It connotes a level of hardship that *extremes* doesn't. Thus, *help in extremity* means help in desperate situations. *Help in extremes* doesn't sound quite right.

Particularly with the popularization of "extreme sports" and "extreme lifestyles", *extremes* can sometimes have a positive connotation that *extremity* can't.

There are also places where either word can be used with equal impact. In a desperate situation, you might be *driven to extremities* or *driven to extremes* - both mean drastic action.

Comment: Though to be honest, depending on how you word the subtitle, any of the three words could be suitable. "Extreme Anger", "Anger in Extremes", etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Extremities* is used for concrete things that are far apart, *extremes* for abstract things. It sounds as if it's the latter that you want for your sub-chapter.